# How to add symbol to each word of input and echo back with initial formatting? (PHP)

Tags: php, input

What I'm trying to do is to input a list of strings containing words via textarea, and add + to each word within these strings.

When I'm exploding with ' ' the first word of each line obviously is not added as separate item. When I use preg_split or 2 loops - formatting is lost, and I'm getting echoed just a long line instead of several strings.
Question is - how to correctly split all strings into words, add symbol to each of them, and then combine them back and output back to user without loosing formatting (such as newlines)?

Since I'm newbie there is surely should be some easy way to do that, but I was unable to find it.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <form class="form-group" action="" method="post" >
                <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="un"></textarea> 

                <input  class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
          </form>
    </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-1">
                <?php 
                    $counter = 0; 
                        if (isset($_POST['un'])) {
                                $input = nl2br($_POST["un"]);
                                $rows = explode("\n", $input);
                                $words = array();
                                foreach($rows as $row) {
                                    $temp = explode(" ", $row);
                                    foreach($temp as $word)
                                        echo "+" . $word;
                                }

                            }

                ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: You have too many unclosed questions, IMHO. Have any not been solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use str_ireplace.  This can replace text in a string with something else.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php

You have defined a new word as something following a " " or following a "\n".  Just use str_ireplace to change " " to "+" and "\n" to "\n+".  I suppose you'll also need to remove the final "+" if the end of the string is "\n" as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response, Patrick. I was able to solve it indian way:

```
 $input =$_POST["un"];
                        $textToStore = nl2br(htmlentities($input, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                        $arrayWords = str_replace(" ", " +", $textToStore); 
                        $arrayWords = "+" . $arrayWords; 
                        $arrayWords = str_replace("\n", "\n+", $arrayWords); 
                        echo $arrayWords;
```

Will post, if I find more elegant solution.